# Store hourly clicks with sharded counter in google appengine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, bigtable, sharding

I'm developing an app in python for google app engine that count different kind of clicks with sharded counters.

My problem is that I want to get statistics split by hour from the clicks and not just a total sum of all clicks.

One way to achieve that is to add a timestamp to the index of the shards:

```
def txn():
  index = random.randint(0, config.num_shards - 1)
  shard_name = code + str(index) # + timestamp without seconds
  counter = ClickCounter.get_by_key_name(shard_name)
  if counter is None:
    counter = ClickCounter(key_name=shard_name, code=code)
  counter.click += 1
  counter.put()
db.run_in_transaction(txn)
```

The problem would be that counting all the shards for a month would be more than 700 times slower.

Is there a good way to cache the results? I mean, once an hour has passed the counter won't change any more. Is there a drawback with saving every click in a new object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution will work - just use the task queue to aggregate your sharded records into nice, reporting-friendly, summary records as you go.

Comment: hmm... will a task queue work even with heavy load? More than 100 request/sec?

Comment: I solved it by using task queues and adding an hourly report model as well. Thanks!